# poclbm not reporting hashes to deepbit or slush

Tags: bitcoin, mining

I run poclbm on my system but for some reason both deepbit and slush don't "see" the work being performed. My system reports about 200 megabashes per second being done. I tried mining with my cpu using the same settings, and then both deepbit and slush recognized that work was being performed.

These are the errors I am getting out of the respective mining hardware (every minute or so):

> **poclbm error:** pit.deepbit.net:8332 22/02/2013 21:50:59, Verification failed, check hardware! (0:0:Cypress, d47b7ba0)
>
> **cgminer error:** [2013-02-22 22:18:51] GPU0: invalid nonce - HW error

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) with the 12.10 version poclbm with an  ATI 5800 series video card. The video drivers are installed and work as far as I can tell. When I run a "aticonfig --odgc --adapter=all", the gpu does seem to be utilized with poclbm (around 70% utilization or so).

Comment: Probably a better fit for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution through an irc channel (Freenode on channcel #cgminer). Basically, at least on the version of Ubuntu that I have (12.10), the 2.8 version of the SDK does NOT work properly with cgminer or poclbm. I was instructed to download the 2.4 version of the SDK. Here:
http://developer.amd.com/Downloads/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.4-lnx32.tgz
http://developer.amd.com/Downloads/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.4-lnx64.tgz

Some distributions require the "2.7" version so I'll put the links here:
http://developer.amd.com/Downloads/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.7-lnx32.tgz
http://developer.amd.com/Downloads/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.7-lnx64.tgz

I compiled it. There is no "make install" for this Makefile, apparently, so you have to manually copy the files to your lib directory:

> for 32 bit: $ cp -pv lib/x86/* /usr/lib/
>
> for 64 bit: $ cp -pv lib/x86_64/* /usr/lib/
>
> Also copy the include files: $ rsync -avl include/CL/ /usr/include/CL/

With the libraries installed in the appropriate directories, I recompiled cgminer and then it worked. I also tried it with poclbm and it worked with that too.

Comment: I had to install SDK 2.7 to get it to work on Mint 14, but thank you very much.

Comment: FYI SDK 2.4 doesn't work with the latest version of archlinux. I tried 2.7 and it worked for me.

Comment: Is this for bitcoins or litecoins?

Answer (score -1):

Hm, I experienced the same error with pclbm and cgminer. Then I found https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=139406.msg1502120#msg1502120 .. I tried phoenix and all is ok now. Hope it helps. Sry my bad english.